# PyQt: how to display a treeview or other complex widget as tooltip

Tags: qt, treeview, pyqt, tooltip

I'm working on a PyQt project. I have a map with points on it (The map is a QGraphicsScene and my points are QGraphicsEllipseItem).
I would like to display some informations on the points when they receive a hover event.
The information will be: a picture, some text and a treeview fill with data.
I don't want to open a new window, I want it to float over the map exactly how a tooltip will do.

I don't know how to do it, I can't find any widget who fill my needs.

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new widget/window with windowflag Qt::ToolTip. According to the docs Qt's tooltips are nothing else. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

Comment: It's quite educational to look through the [qt source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/kernel/qtooltip.cpp) to see how opening and hiding tooltips happens as there are many little details that need to be taken into consideration.